# Using URL Parameters in Protected Routes in React + Firestore

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I'm creating an app that has group functionalities, and I wanna restrict access to a group based on whether or not a user is specified inside of a field in a firestore document or not. The ID of the group is passed in via a URL parameter `(blahblah.com/groups/:id)` and I want to be able to access that ID parameter in my custom route. With the code below, I get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'params' of undefined`.

```
 <Router>
   <Switch>
     <GroupRoute exact path = "/groups/:id" component = {GroupDash}/>
     <PrivateRoute exact path = "/UserProfile" component = {UserProfile}/>
   </Switch>
 </Router>
```

Other Code

```
export const GroupRoute = ({component: RouteComponent, match, ...rest}) => {
    const {currentUser} = useContext(AuthContext);
    const groupID = match.params.id;
    let validRoute = false;
    let members  = [];
    const groupRef = db.collection('Groups').doc(groupID)
    groupRef.get().then(snapshot => {
            let data = snapshot.data()
            let temp = data.groupMembers
            temp.forEach(element => {
                members.push(element.uid)
            })
            validRoute = members.includes(currentUser.uid);
        }
    )
    return (
        <Route
            {...rest}
            render= {routeProps => validRoute ? (<RouteComponent{...routeProps}/>):(<Redirect to = {"/UserDash"}/>)}
        />
    )

}
```

How do I access the id parameter inside the GroupRoute component?

Comment: A component can't receive route props *before* the defined `Route`, even using the `useParams` hook within it. Confirmed in this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-kepler-2jeyd?expanddevtools=1&fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&initialpath=%2Fgroups%2F42&module=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js&theme=dark) it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Match Param is only available to GroupRoute once it is rendered by the Route and that too it will not be directly accesible within the GroupRoute component.

Also you must note that you are trying to write a async code directly in render which isn't correct.

One solution is to write this logic in a inner component rendered at the route like below

```
const GroupRouteInner = ({RouteComponent, match, history, ...rest}) => {
    const {currentUser} = useContext(AuthContext);
    const [loading, setLoading] = true;
    const groupID = match.params.id;

    let members  = [];
    useEffect(() => {
       const groupRef = db.collection('Groups').doc(groupID)
        groupRef.get().then(snapshot => {
            let data = snapshot.data()
            let temp = data.groupMembers
            temp.forEach(element => {
                members.push(element.uid)
            })
            let validRoute = validRoute = members.includes(currentUser.uid);
            if(!validRoute) {
                history.push('/UserDash');
            }
            setLoading(false);
        })
    }, [groupID])

    if(loading) return <div>Loading...</div>
    return <RouteComponent match={match} history={history} {...rest} />
}
export const GroupRoute = ({component: RouteComponent, ...rest}) => {

    return (
        <Route
            {...rest}
            component={(rProps) => <GroupRouteInner {...rProps} RouteComponent={RouteComponent}/>}
        />
    )

}
```